# Power BI generate future date with last known value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I need assistance to generate future date with the last known value in Power BI
I have data as below:

| Date | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec-20 | PC | 20000 |
| Dec-20 | PLOB | 50000 |
| Jan-21 | PC | 30000 |
| Jan-21 | PLOB | 40000 |
| Feb-21 | PC | 50000 |
| Feb-21 | PLOB | 60000 |
| Mar-21 | PC | 20000 |
| Mar-21 | PLOB | 50000 |
| Apr-21 | PC | 60000 |
| Apr-21 | PLOB | 70000 |

I need to generate the below table:

| Date | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec-20 | PC | 20000 |
| Dec-20 | PLOB | 50000 |
| Jan-21 | PC | 30000 |
| Jan-21 | PLOB | 40000 |
| Feb-21 | PC | 50000 |
| Feb-21 | PLOB | 60000 |
| Mar-21 | PC | 20000 |
| Mar-21 | PLOB | 50000 |
| Apr-21 | PC | 60000 |
| Apr-21 | PLOB | 70000 |
| May-21 | PC | **60000** |
| May-21 | PLOB | **70000** |
| : | : | : |
| Dec-21 | PLOB | **60000** |
| Dec-21 | PLOB | **70000** |

Kindly assist me with DAX calculation

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following, the steps are

1. Create a list of the Present Months
2. Calculate the maximum month
3. Get the distinct categories
4. Generate a list of all future months contain in 2021, and calculate with `ADDCOLUMNS` the start of the months.
5. Take only the future months using `EXCEPT`
6. Cross Join the future months with the distinct categories, that would give you all the combinations possible.
7. `ADDCOLUMNS` to the `CROSSJOIN` table, where `[value]` is calculated using the `[variable]` name and the max month from the table you provided. `VAR` is used to access the row context, so we can use `FILTER`.

### Calculated Table

```
Future =
VAR PresentMonths =
    ALL ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR maxMonth =
    MAXX ( 'Table', [Date] )
VAR DistinctCat =
    ALL ( 'Table'[variable] )
VAR AllMonths =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2021, 01, 01 ), DATE ( 2021, 12, 31 ) ),
            "MonthStart", DATE ( YEAR ( [Date] ), MONTH ( [Date] ), 01 )
        ),
        [MonthStart]
    )
VAR FutureMonths =
    EXCEPT ( AllMonths, PresentMonths )
VAR FutureTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CROSSJOIN ( FutureMonths, DistinctCat ),
        "value",
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Table'[value] ),
                VAR localVariable = [variable]
                RETURN
                    FILTER ( 'Table', [variable] = localVariable && [Date] = maxMonth )
            )
    )
RETURN
    UNION ( 'Table', FutureTable )
```

### Output

| Date | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| December 2020 | PLOB | 50000 |
| December 2020 | PC | 20000 |
| January 2021 | PC | 30000 |
| January 2021 | PLOB | 40000 |
| February 2021 | PC | 50000 |
| February 2021 | PLOB | 60000 |
| March 2021 | PC | 20000 |
| March 2021 | PLOB | 50000 |
| April 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| April 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| May 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| May 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| June 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| June 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| July 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| July 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| August 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| August 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| September 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| September 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| October 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| October 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| November 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| November 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |
| December 2021 | PC | 60000 |
| December 2021 | PLOB | 70000 |

Comment: Thank you So much, Angelo. Working as expected. Good Explanation.

Comment: Excellent, Is it possible you can mark the answer as the solution?